# Select column if exist in table 2 or exist in table 3 or table 4

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a query. I have 4 tables

```
first table: person
ID_No
-----
1
2
3

second table: update_general_details
Update_ID  ID_No Email           Mob_No
---------  ----- -------------- -------- 
1          1     some@gmail.com 078231231

third table: update_training
Training_ID ID_No Training_Name  Training-Date
----------- ----  -------------  -------------
1            2    Mysql training 2014-09-09

third table: update_award
Award_ID ID_No Award_Name  Award_Year
-------- ----- ----------- ----------
1        1     Best in Math  2010
```

What I am trying to do is to select distinct ID numbers where the ID number could contain in the second table or third or fourth.
Desired result:

```
ID_No
  1
  2
```

Here is my code:

```
Select DISTINCT person.ID_No, 
from update_award, update_general, update_training, person
where EXISTS (SELECT update_award.ID_No
          FROM update_award, person
          WHERE person.ID_No = update_award.ID_No) or

          EXISTS (SELECT update_training.ID_No
          FROM update_training, person
          WHERE person.ID_No = update_training.ID_No) or

          EXISTS (SELECT update_general_details.ID_No
          FROM update_general, person
          WHERE person.ID_No = update_general.ID_No)
```

this query returns nothing. Thank you in advance

Comment: You appear to have trouble counting to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the detail tables from the main query and the person table from the subqueries, that should help a lot:

```
Select person.ID_No
from person
where EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM update_award
  WHERE person.ID_No = update_award.ID_No
) 
or EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM update_training
  WHERE person.ID_No = update_training.ID_No
) or EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM update_general
  WHERE person.ID_No = update_general.ID_No
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is the ID, you can skip the `person` table, and just query the other three directly. Using `union` will remove any duplicates:

```
SELECT update_award.ID_No
FROM   update_award
UNION
SELECT update_training.ID_No
FROM   update_training
UNION
SELECT update_general_details.ID_No
FROM   update_general
```